# How do I get Apache to use the default pyenv Python version instead of the system one?

Tags: python, apache

I am using plain Apache 2.4 on Mac OS Catalina.

I installed pyenv to manage python versions.
The default Python is 3.8.0

Now I try to have Python scripts running in Apache.
I created a subdomain under localhost that makes sure python code will run.
But it seems to use the system python version(s) and not the one from pyenv.

When I use shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Then python 2 is used. Not what I want...

When I use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

It uses the system python3 version (3.7.3)
Which is the python at /usr/bin/python3

How do I get Apache to use the "default" python that I see when I execute: "pyenv global"?

Answer (score 1):

If the `python` version you want to use is:

```
/opt/local/bin/python
```

just replace the 1st line of the scripts you want to run with this
version of `python` to say you want to use this interpreter:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python
```